# UML association with respect to code

Tags: java, uml

I understand code fully however I'm having a bit of trouble understanding UML as it relates to code.

Question 1 - If I have a class

```
public class one
{....}

public class two
{
    one ob;
    public two(){ob=new one();}
}
```

I know this is an association but do I show this in a class diagram with an arrow or not?

[image]

Question 2 - if I have the following class

```
public class three
{
   public three(){.........}

   public void method() {  one obt=new one();  }
}
```

Is this an association between class three and class one? I'm not sure since its being applied from the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this is an association but do I show this in a class diagram with an arrow or not?

If class `one` has no reference to class `two` then you should have an arrow head.  But it points from `two` to `one` (opposite way to how you have it shown).  Reason: the arrow indicates navigability.  Class `two` can navigate to class `one` because it holds an instance.  The opposite is not true.  Technically it should be an open arrowhead, not the closed form you've used.

> Is this an association between class three and class one? I'm not sure since its being applied from the method.

If the only reference from `three` to `one` is as a method parameter then you'd most likely show as a dependency not an association.  Associations declare a systematic relationship among the entities - like a `Purchase Order` consisting of `Order Lines`.  In code that most often translates to a member variable (or collection thereof).  Dependencies are a weaker form of relationship than Associations and don't imply a systematic link.

hth.

Comment: One thing to correct: The arrow indicates navigability (not visibility). No arrows means the association is navigable in both directions. (Which btw. does not necessarily mean that there's an member variable for it.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all the arrow is in the other direction, from `two` to `one` since `two` points at `one`. If you don't show it with an arrow you are saying that you don't know the direction of the relations - it can be both `one` calling `two` and `two` calling `one`. Since you know that `two` owns `one`, you should add the arrow direction.

Regarding your second question, yes this is a relation from `three` to `one` since `three` requires `one`. This relation can be a dependency or association, depending on what `three` does with `one`.